# WriteHTML / Euro symbol in TCPDF not displaying correctly

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I've read all the other threads and tried everything. Here's where I'm at:

Constructor:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
```

I'm running utf8_encode on the buffer before doing writeHTML.

I have tried € the exact reference, pasting the character raw, changing the constructor to UTF8 seems to add random A's with accents on around my document...

Not sure at this point.

My other question is styling using writeHTML... I have tables because TCPDF's writeHTML function doesn't really include the box model seemingly. For instance I have this code:

```
<td valign="top" align="left" style="padding:0;">
        <table width="193" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td style="text-align:left;" align="left" valign="top" width="193" style="width:193px;">
        <?php
        $imageCount = count($theImages);
        for($i = 1; $i <= $imageCount; $i++)
        {
          $f = SITE_ROOT . '/i/properties/'. $p->id .'/l_'. $theImages[$i]['name'];
          $u = '/i/properties/'. $p->id .'/l_'. $theImages[$i]['name'];
          if(file_exists($f)) {
            echo '<img src="'.$u.'" width="193" /></td></tr><tr><td>';
          }
        }
        ?></td></tr></table>
      </td>
```

Just an extract, and the first image is aligned to the eft, even though it's all 193? I have spent a fair day or two on this so far, and if anyone has any alternatives for creating nicely styled property data sheets, integrating with a content managed php site, please let me know! :) Otherwise any answers to my problems would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create your PDF using the encoding `ISO-8859-1` which has the distinct disadvantage of not having the Euro sign. You can either

- Quick and dirty, not recommended: Change to `ISO-8859-15` (which is compatible with `ISO-8859-1` but has the Euro sign)

or

- Better: Change to `UTF-8` and make sure, all your text ist correctly encoded to `UTF-8` before throwing it at the PDF generator

Comment: Sorry, I pass on the layout: We gave up on it, and now we create one image per page and include only the image in the PDF, in fact making the PDF just a wrapper for the image.

Comment: Mmm. This sounds like the right answer. I've tried your changes... and it doesn't seem to be working :S trying: <?php echo $euro; ?>&euro; &#8364; $euro = $pdf->unichr(8364);

Comment: Obviously I changed it to $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-8859-15', false); and added 
      header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15'); for peace of mind.